# Parsing JSon in Classic ASP with ASP Xtreme Evolution

Tags: json, asp-classic

I'm working on an classic ASP-project and I use ASP Xtreme Evolution to parse JSon data (found here: http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/entries/classic-asp-json-revisited/)

Anyway... I'm getting most of the JSon-data correctly but now I'm stuck on an Array.

The JSon looks like this:

```
{
  "Product": {
    "ID": "6666",
    "Name": "Tha name",
    "ArticleGroup": [
      {
        "@handleas": "array",
        "Title": "Title 1",
        "Article": {
          "ID": "777",
          "Label": "Label 1",
        }
      },
      {
        "@handleas": "array",
        "Title": "Title 2",
        "Article": {
          "ID": "888",
          "Label": "Label 2",
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the ASP look like this:

```
set xmlHTTP = server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHTTP.open "GET", "http://source.of.json", false
xmlHTTP.send()
ProductFeed = xmlHTTP.ResponseText

dim ProductInfo : set ProductInfo = JSON.parse(join(array(ProductFeed)))

    dim key : for each key in ProductInfo.Product.keys()
        Response.Write ProductInfo.Product.ID ' Prints 6666
        Response.Write ProductInfo.Product.Name ' Prints Tha Name
    Next
    set ProductInfo = nothing
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to access the information in ArticleGroup. All I get is [object Object],[object Object] or an empty value.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (based on the given JSON):

```
Dim ArticleGroup

dim key : For Each key in ProductInfo.Product.keys()
    Response.Write ProductInfo.Product.ID ' Prints 6666
    Response.Write ProductInfo.Product.Name ' Prints Tha Name            

    For Each ArticleGroup In ProductInfo.Product.Get("ArticleGroup") '' iterate all ArticleGroup entries
        Response.write ArticleGroup.Get("Title") '' get the correct key value
    Next
Next
```

You need to iterate all ArticleGroup entries and get the value through `.get(keyName)`. Otherwise it will return the JScript function body instead.

Comment: It works great! Do you also know how to use in when the "ArticleGroup" only contains one sub-group? The "For Each"-function throws an error when ArticleGroup i less than two.

Comment: I don't get an error with onlt one ArticleGroup. Could you supply JSON example that fails?

Comment: Sorry I think I was a bit unclear. I ment when the ArticleGroup has only one: {
        "@handleas": "array",
        "Title": "Title 2",
        "Article": {
          "ID": "888",
          "Label": "Label 2",
        }